# How do I force HTML form input formatting?

Tags: html, forms, format

I am trying to add auto formatting to some of my form input fields. For example when the "phone number" input field is clicked I want to force the formatting to be (**_) - _** - ___

You can see an example here under the phone number: https://www.alliantcreditunion.com/Applications/los/Personal

My client doesn't want placeholders or pattern requirements. So how can I force the formatting?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this plug-in (if you don't mind using a third-party plug-in):

http://robinherbots.github.io/jquery.inputmask/